# Power BI DAX - Grouping rows when a value is found in row

Tags: powerbi, grouping, dax

I have the below table. I need to group them base on product and increment group number when set = 1 but returns back to 1 if new product is in next line. I have created an index already.

| Index | Product | Set |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Table | 0 |
| 2 | Table | 0 |
| 3 | Table | 1 |
| 4 | Table | 0 |
| 5 | Table | 0 |
| 6 | Table | 1 |
| 7 | Table | 0 |
| 8 | Table | 1 |
| 9 | Chair | 0 |
| 10 | Chair | 0 |
| 11 | Chair | 0 |
| 12 | Chair | 1 |
| 13 | Chair | 0 |
| 14 | Chair | 0 |
| 15 | Chair | 1 |

Here's the result I'm after:

| Index | Product | Set | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Table | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Table | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | Table | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Table | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | Table | 0 | 2 |
| 6 | Table | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | Table | 0 | 3 |
| 8 | Table | 1 | 3 |
| 9 | Chair | 0 | 1 |
| 10 | Chair | 0 | 1 |
| 11 | Chair | 0 | 1 |
| 12 | Chair | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | Chair | 0 | 2 |
| 14 | Chair | 0 | 2 |
| 15 | Chair | 1 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this

```
Grouping=
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        'fact',
        'fact'[Set] <> 0
            && EARLIER ( 'fact'[Product] ) = 'fact'[Product]
    ),
    'fact'[Index],
    ,
    ASC
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Really like the solution, that's a clever way of using the Index!